# How to create _extend_child.less for grand children theme

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, less, luma-theme, parent-child-theme

I am new to `Magento 2`. I am having difficulty in creating a child theme. However I have created the child theme now I am facing how to add source for child them.

In my configuration, I have created child theme of `Luma`, which is child theme of `Magento blank` theme. I want to extend all css from either parent or grand parent. So decided to not give same name which already exist in parent theme (`luma`).

I am planning to add `_extend-child.less` to the parent theme and keep it blank. And creating same filename in child theme where I can add my own CSS or can add call child sources. Now my question is:

1. As luma theme is primarily present in vendor directory. I cannot add `_extend-child.less` here as it might override on upgrade. How could I copy this to `app/design/frontend/Magento` directory?
2. Does copying the complete folder `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/` to `app/design/frontend/Magento/` would work?
3. Does changing code on `app/design/frontend/Magento/` would not be affected on theme update/upgrade?
4. Any standard way to include my child CSS to luma theme.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you extend from Luma, you have all CSS of Luma. If you want to extend e.g. Magento_Checkout, you would create _extend.less in Magento_Checkout/web/css/source

If you want to override this CSS completely you would create _module.less.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html